# I have been working on wordpress and stuck in an issue difficult to manage

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Their is an issue in this wordpress url :

**https://example.com/usa-drug-alcohol-testing-locations/ohio-oh/delaware-alcohol-drug-testing-screening-services-4/**

**https://example.com/usa-drug-alcohol-testing-locations/ohio-oh/delaware-alcohol-drug-testing-screening-services-2/**

I want to hide **-4 or -2 or -3** from title slug through .htaccess.

What should I do to get rid of this issue from following URLs?

Comment: Why through `.htaccess`? Why not remove the `-#` from the actual URL?

Comment: Their are 35000 post stored in database, hence give your views according to it. Please....

Comment: I don't want to remove -2 or -3 or -4 but to hide this from url. Its functionality should remain same.

Answer (score 3):

When more than one post or a page have the same slug, the WordPress inserts those unique identifiers.

So solution is to find those posts / pages and edit their permalinks to something unique.